# Change a amsthm theorem ending

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I am writing a text where the editor suggested to close all the definitions with a diamond.

So I was wondering, is there a easy way to automatically add a command to all the `\end{definition}` ? I looked the documentation of `\theoremstyle`, but it does not really seem to help.

Here is a working example where I did it manually...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\newcommand{\xqed}[1]{%
   \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
   \quad\hbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Endofdef}{\xqed{\lozenge}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
(Stack Overflow) Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site
of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky,
as a more open alternative to earlier Q\&A sites such as Experts Exchange.\Endofdef
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your copy editor is wrong, but unfortunately you can't do much about this, save insisting you don't want it. Anyway, it's a duplicate (where the `\xqed` command seems to come from). My solution there works even for definitions nested in `proof` environments.

Comment: I am not sure, are you the author of ```ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/extra-qed.tex``` ? There is where I read the ```xqed``` definition.

Comment: egreg is not the author of your cited reference; i am.  adding the ability to insert an end-of-theorem mark comparable to the end-of-proof mark is on the list of requested features for `amsthm`, to be considered the next time that is updated.  (but i can't predict when an update might happen.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Still I'd prefer the `\pushQED` approach.

Comment: @egreg -- well, `\pushQED` is how the end-of-proof mark is implemented, so (of course) that's how we'd implement the comparable feature for theorems.  the document cited by the original poster in his comment is just a stopgap until an update to `amsthm` is undertaken.  what do you think of the idea of putting in a test for vertical mode, and issuing a warning if that's true?  (maybe even an error, but many variations of "endings" would have to be tested first to make sure we're not backing ourselves into a corner.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton A blank line before `\end{<env>}` would indeed be disastrous. Users should be made aware of `\qedhere`. A test should check for vertical mode or nothing in the current horizontal list (the latter is not easy).

Comment: @egreg -- we see blank lines in this situation all the time, sometimes with the tombstone broken to the next page, and it makes the production editors earn their keep.  i think the "nothing in the horizontal list" is not nearly so common -- that would require real effort.  i'll add the suggestion about a vertical mode check to the `amsthm` request list.  (we do try to make authors aware of `\qedhere`, but so many are so proud that they don't ever read documentation!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new environment `mydef` and insert the symbol just before to close it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newenvironment{mydef}[1]{%
    \begin{definition}#1}{%
    \Endofdef\end{definition}%
}

\newcommand{\xqed}[1]{%
    \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
    \quad\hbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Endofdef}{\xqed{\lozenge}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{mydef}[Stack Overflow] Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site
        of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky,
        as a more open alternative to earlier Q\&A sites such as Experts Exchange.
    \end{mydef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thought of that, but if I leave an empty line before the ```\end``` it won't show well. It is true that the ```proof``` environment does the same, but I was hoping in more robust solution. But ok.

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni, since AMS proof also does this I believe that it is not possible to remove new paragraphs before the closing.

Comment: You are probably right, accepted.

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni -- it is not possible to backtrack out of vertical mode when the input of a theorem or proof ends with a blank line.  however, a test for vertical mode could be added to the definition of `\xqed`, and a warning issued if it is true.

Answer (score 0):

If you can consider using `ntheorem`, it's easy to incorporate a symbol at the end of any theorem type environment. It has the advantage that its placement is automatic, even if the environment ends up in displayed equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\scalebox{1}[1.4]{\large$ \diamond $}}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{A Demo Section}
\begin{definition}
(Stack Overflow) Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site
of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky,
as a more open alternative to earlier Q\&A sites such as Experts Exchange.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
A \textbf{Pythagorean triple} is a triple $ (x, y, z) $ of integers such that
    \[ x² + y² = z² . \]%
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]